# Android Eclipse Juno will not allow me to update software. ADT 22 from 20

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

When I open Eclipse Juno, I get a dialog box that says "The Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 22.0.0 or above. Current version is 20.0.3v201208082019-427395. Please update ADT to the latest version."

When I go to Help>Install New Software>Add, and then put in the correct information and go through the following steps, at the end it gives me the error that I am not allowed to update software.

I have also attempted to install new software using the Archive button and adding an ADT 22.0.1 zip folder.

Comment: Why not Help->Check for Updates?

Comment: I've tried that. It says "No updates were found."

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to update the Android Toolkit from the Android SDK Manager. It will appear near the bottom of that list. Just update from there and Eclipse should work.

Comment: Any and all updating I attempt to do is not allowed. I either get a "file not found" error when attempting to update from the Android SDK Manager, or "Android Developer Tools will be ignored because it is already installed" error when using Help > Install New Software > Add.